# Mysql user auth doen't work

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, cgi, authentication

I'm working around with some php + mysql and for user authentication. I've implemented this:

```
<?php

    if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']))
    {
            header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Administrator"');
            header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
            echo  'Username and password are required to view this page';
            exit;
    }
    else
    {
            if(isset($_ENV["OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST"]))
            {

                    $conn = mysql_connect($_ENV["OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST"].':'.$_ENV["OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT"],
                                          $_ENV["OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME"],
                                          $_ENV["OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD"]) or die(mysql_error());
            }
            else
            {
                    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error());
            }
            mysql_select_db("db", $conn) or die(mysql_error());
            $sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM admin_users";
            $result = mysql_query($sqlquery, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
            $access_granted = 0;
            while($user = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                    if ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == $user['user_name'] &&
                        $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] == $user['password'])
                    {
                            $access_granted++;
                    }
            }
            if(!$access_granted)
            {
                    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Administrator"');
                    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
                    echo "Invalid username and/or password";
                    exit;
            }
    }
?>
```

The user, pass, table, etc are correct but it's not working properly, no redirect but no errors also

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you turned error reporting on? (`<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
 ?>`)

Comment: It just may be so that one of the results validates your `if` condition and and makes `access_granted` NON 0, due to which you are there on the same page

Comment: I forgot to say I'm running on apache server, and if setup in wamp locally it work fine but not in my server

Comment: @bSaraogi yes it's always the same page for all app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is about my based CGI server and the way it deals with header auth

adding this into .htaccess solves the issue

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
</IfModule>
```